# c++ placement new how to construct an object

Tags: c++, stl, new-operator

When I read the code for tinystl, I find the following code

```
struct placeholder{};
void* operator new(size_t, placeholder, void *ptr)
{
    return ptr;
}
```

Why it needs a placeholder? What is the difference between the above and the below code?

```
void *operator new(size_t, void *ptr)
{
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: The difference is precisely the presence of `placeholder`, which is needed to differentiate this `operator new` from the other one.

Answer (score 0):

See this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Its the alignment.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers, add a summary of the linked content.